# Cannot read property of undefined - issue with code or servers?

Tags: javascript, json, apache, tomcat

I am working on an application that uses AngularJS for the front-end and Java (Spring) for the back-end. The app makes a request `http://localhost:8080/Sprint002/restpatent/` so I have both Apache and Tomcat running (Apache on port 80).

The error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'fetchAllUsers' of undefined` is returned. So what I can see is that no object has been found. Is the issue with running Apache and Tomcat simultaneously, if not, what is the reason?

```
app.controller('UserController', ['UserService', function($scope, UserService) {


var self = this;
self.user={id:null,username:'',address:'',email:''};
self.users=[];
self.submit = submit;
self.edit = edit;
self.remove = remove;
self.reset = reset;
console.log('hello')


fetchAllUsers();

function fetchAllUsers(){
    console.log('hello2');
    UserService.fetchAllUsers()
        .then(
        function(d) {
            self.users = d;
        },
        function(errResponse){
            console.error('Error while fetching Users');
        }
    );
}
```

---

```
app.factory('UserService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){ 
    console.log('hello3')

var REST_SERVICE_URI = 'http://localhost:8080/Sprint002/restpatent/';

var factory = {
    fetchAllUsers: fetchAllUsers,
    createUser: createUser,
    updateUser:updateUser,
    deleteUser:deleteUser
};

return factory;

function fetchAllUsers() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
      console.log('hello4')
    $http.get(REST_SERVICE_URI)
        .then(
        function (response) { //success
            deferred.resolve(response.data); //processes the data
        },
        function(errResponse){ //error
            console.error('Error while fetching Users');
            deferred.reject(errResponse); //rejects the data
        }
    );
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

---

```
[{"id":1,"applicationNumber":"N8167625","clientRef":"TER-34421","costToRenew":"534","renewalDueDate":"30/09/2017","basketStatus":"Cannot add to Basket"},{"id":2,"applicationNumber":"W71679234","clientRef":"Breitling","costToRenew":"5367","renewalDueDate":"30/11/2017","basketStatus":"Add to Basket"},{"id":3,"applicationNumber":"T7167921","clientRef":"Rolex","costToRenew":"8341","renewalDueDate":"30/05/2017","basketStatus":"In Basket"},{"id":4,"applicationNumber":"uk167444","clientRef":"Timex","costToRenew":"8341","renewalDueDate":"30/02/2017","basketStatus":"Add to Basket"}]
```

Comment: can you s how where do you inject this factory and you call your method please?

Comment: Updated just now

Comment: you have an error injecting. answered, let's try that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
app.controller('UserController', ['UserService', function($scope, UserService)
```

to this:

```
app.controller('UserController', ['$scope', 'UserService', function($scope, UserService)
```

Comment: OMG. That was it! What was the issue? I understand the `$scope` wasn't included but I only thought the reason for including a square bracket syntax was to include dependencies and/or if you were to minify your code? Have I got that totally wrong? Anyhow thank you!

Comment: When you use that syntax, you have to be careful that the order is the same among the ones with square brackets and the one inside the round brackets. This solution is the better if you want to uglify/minify your code, but you can also get rid of this redundancy and use ng-annotate to automatically do it when deploying your code. 
This last solution is the one I can suggest you because you do it directly before to minify/uglify the code. Does it make sense?

Comment: So if I am to use a square bracket syntax, make sure to include every parameter that have been passed in the function?

Comment: exactly, and with the same order. Actually the names you use inside your round brackets are the references to the dependencies you are injecting in the square ones

Comment: no problem :) Please if this fixed your issue, mark the answer as correct so that it can be useful for other people with the same issue.
p.s. if you are using a task runner, most probably ng-annotate has already corresponding versions to the task runner you are using